# How to apply FBMemoryProfiler to cocos2d-x iOs game?

Tags: ios, memory, cocos2d-x

I want to apply the `FBMemoryProfiler` for cocos2dx iOs game.

First, I create a simple demo, "`cocos new CocosGame -p com.test -l cpp`". There are a lot of projects of the demo, like `proj.ios_mac`, `proj.android`, `proj.linux`...
I chose the `ios_mac` one and it works fine.

Then, I create a podfile to import the `FBMemoryProfiler` in `proj.ios_mac` and I use podfile to install `FBMemoryProfiler`.

However, when I open the `CococsGame.xcworkkspace`, there are a lot of errors, like

> cannot find libFBAllocationTracker.a

I really want to know how to apply FBMemoryProfiler for cocos2d, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include FBAllocationTracker in your demo first.

You can do that by including the following

```
import FBAllocationTracker
```

in the headers and in the main method

```
FBAllocationTrackerManager.sharedManager()?.startTrackingAllocations()
```

into your main.swift

PS: You might wanna enable Generations by adding the following line with the above :

```
FBAllocationTrackerManager.sharedManager()?.enableGenerations()
```

If you have already done the above and still getting the same error, it looks like your project is not linking the FBAllocationTracker properly and you might wanna look at the https://github.com/facebook/FBMemoryProfiler "Usage" section again to see if you are missing something.